# How to backup and restore configurations

Tags: backup, configuration

I am in the process of transferring my WordPress blog to a new host. I've copied the blog files, used XML import/export to copy the contents, and the blog is now up and running.

The missing piece is configuration. At the new blog, all the plugins are turned off, the widget are set to default and the plugin settings (e.g. Google Analytics code) are not set.

**How do I transfer my configuration and plugin settings from my old blog?**

Comment: copy the whole database. Read [`Moving WordPress`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must export all table beginning with your WordPress prefix.

1. Open your phpmyadmin panel.
2. Then open your wordpress database.
3. Click "export" from top menu.
4. Select "Export Method:" as custom.
5. Select your all tables beginning your prefix.
6. Then go to bottom of page click "go".

You got your SQL file. Move all files to new directory. If you create a new database on new host, you must change the database name on wp-config.php.

- Then you must import your SQL file to new database.
- Replace the old domain name with the new domain name. Go to wp_options table on your database.
- Change siteurl option name. on second page change "home" option name with new url.

Comment: Is there a plugin that makes this task easier?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Comment: that will work for sure

Answer (score 1):

If you like the command line WordPress you can do it like this:

```
wp db export
wp db import
wp export
wp import
```

https://wp-cli.org/commands/export/

https://wp-cli.org/commands/import/

http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/

Answer (score 0):

I always used plugin: [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/). Works fine. Simple, easy and don't necessary heavy WP user/programmer to install and use.